# How can I solve $\left(y + y\sqrt{x^2y^4 +1}\right) \, dx + 2 x \, dy = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\left(y + y\sqrt{x^2y^4 +1}\right) \, dx + 2 x \, dy = 0$$

I have always use integrating factors to solve these kind of equations, but it doesn't work with this one. What should I try? Could you give some ideas?

Comment: @Amzoti Yes, thanks to the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we get:

$$y(1+\sqrt{x^2y^4+1})\; dx = -2x\; dy \\
y' \equiv dy/dx = \frac{-y(1+\sqrt{x^2y^4+1})}{2x} $$

From inspection, I would recommend substituting $v=xy^2$, since this help take the seemingly intractable square root into a function of one variable. Then:

$y^2 + 2xy y' = v'$

and so $\frac{y^2-v'}{y} = -y(1+\sqrt{v^2+1})$, which reduces to:

$v' - y^2(2+\sqrt{v^2+1}) = 0$.

Now this is separable and thus easy to solve.

Comment: Are you sure? It doesn't look like an homogeneous ODE to me...

Comment: @Trollkemada, it is not homogeneous, but fortuantely it is separable. So a substitution is probably needed. Since $\sqrt{x^2y^4+1}$ you probably want to choose $v = xy^2$ (you're quite right that $v=y/x$ will not work)